# Mysterious UIButton crash

Tags: ios, interface-builder, crash, uibutton

I have a `UITableViewCell` that has 2 `UIButton` instances. Both buttons have a default image. Only the "bad" button has an image for the disabled state. Nothing more.

In the cell class these two buttons are declared as properties with the `IBOutlet` keyword:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) IBOutlet UIButton* buttonCall;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) IBOutlet UIButton* buttonGPS;
```

The connections between the 2 buttons in the .xib and the properties in the class are made.

So, when the .xib is loaded the following is done:

```
MyCell* cell = (MyCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
if (nil == cell)
{
    NSArray* nibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCell" owner:nil options:nil];
    cell = [nibContents objectAtIndex:0];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}

// gps button
[cell.buttonGPS setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cell.buttonGPS addTarget:self action:@selector(actionGPS:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

if (...condition...)
{
    cell.buttonCall.enabled = NO;
    [cell.buttonCall removeTarget:self action:@selector(actionCall:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
else
{
    cell.buttonCall.enabled = YES;
    [cell.buttonCall setTitle:[...TheTitleString...] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.buttonCall addTarget:self action:@selector(actionCall:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

When the view controller appears it goes successfully through `(UITableViewCell*)tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` the necessary number of times. Then the app crashes with the following stack:

```
0 kill
...
[UIButton imageRectForContentRect:]
[UIButton(UIButtonInternal) _setupImageView]
[UIButton layoutSubviews]
...
start
```

I removed the image of the button and started crashing with stack:

```
0 kill
...
[UIButton layoutSubviews]
...
start
```

I added some identifier labels for the buttons - still crashing.

Removed the XCode-InterfaceBuilder connection for the "bad" button and the crashes stopped. But the button is not functional.

Any idea what is causing the crashes?

Call stack is:

```
0   CoreFoundation                      0x013d406e __exceptionPreprocess + 206
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x019f0d0a objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x013d5ced -[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 253
3   CoreFoundation                      0x0133af00 ___forwarding___ + 432
4   CoreFoundation                      0x0133ace2 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
5   UIKit                               0x0086de3a -[UIButton imageRectForContentRect:] + 350
6   UIKit                               0x0086ed5b -[UIButton(UIButtonInternal) _setupImageView] + 158
7   UIKit                               0x0086e5f8 -[UIButton layoutSubviews] + 693
8   UIKit                               0x0069f322 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 178
9   CoreFoundation                      0x013d5e72 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 66
10  QuartzCore                          0x0042092d -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 266
11  QuartzCore                          0x0042a827 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 231
12  QuartzCore                          0x003b0fa7 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 377
13  QuartzCore                          0x003b2ea6 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 374
14  QuartzCore                          0x003b2580 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 80
15  CoreFoundation                      0x013a89ce __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
16  CoreFoundation                      0x0133f670 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 384
17  CoreFoundation                      0x0130b4f6 __CFRunLoopRun + 1174
18  CoreFoundation                      0x0130adb4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 212
19  CoreFoundation                      0x0130accb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
20  GraphicsServices                    0x03258879 GSEventRunModal + 207
21  GraphicsServices                    0x0325893e GSEventRun + 114
22  UIKit                               0x00660a9b UIApplicationMain + 1175
23  MyApp                               0x000023f9 main + 169
24  MyApp                               0x00002345 start + 53
```

Exception is:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x146acd8'

info symbol 0x146acd8
__kCFNull in section LC_SEGMENT.__DATA.__data of /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
```

The second scenario is similar. The exception, however, is exactly the same. Here is the call stack:

```
0   CoreFoundation                      0x013d406e __exceptionPreprocess + 206
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x019f0d0a objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x013d5ced -[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 253
3   CoreFoundation                      0x0133af00 ___forwarding___ + 432
4   CoreFoundation                      0x0133ace2 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
5   UIKit                               0x0086e851 -[UIButton layoutSubviews] + 1294
6   UIKit                               0x0069f322 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 178
7   CoreFoundation                      0x013d5e72 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 66
8   QuartzCore                          0x0042092d -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 266
9   QuartzCore                          0x0042a827 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 231
10  QuartzCore                          0x003b0fa7 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 377
11  QuartzCore                          0x003b2ea6 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 374
12  QuartzCore                          0x003b2580 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 80
13  CoreFoundation                      0x013a89ce __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
14  CoreFoundation                      0x0133f670 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 384
15  CoreFoundation                      0x0130b4f6 __CFRunLoopRun + 1174
16  CoreFoundation                      0x0130adb4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 212
17  CoreFoundation                      0x0130accb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
18  GraphicsServices                    0x03258879 GSEventRunModal + 207
19  GraphicsServices                    0x0325893e GSEventRun + 114
20  UIKit                               0x00660a9b UIApplicationMain + 1175
21  MyApp                               0x000023f9 main + 169
22  MyApp                               0x00002345 start + 53
```

Comment: Can we see the crash details?

Comment: Any other information? If you need anything specific just ask.

Comment: What was the actual exception thrown?

Comment: Try to add `@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton* buttonCall;` instead of `@property (nonatomic, readonly) IBOutlet UIButton* buttonCall;`. Is it possible to see implementation method for selector `actionCall:`?

Comment: can u enable the zombie & check the issue once again.

Comment: @vishy No messages are sent to deallocated instances.

Comment: @Flex_Addicted No connection with the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the exception, it looks like you think you are passing an NSString to the title of a button, and you are in fact passing an instance of NSNull. This is quite common if you are deriving your table view data from a JSON source or similar - NSNull is used if the source field does not exist.

The exception you get is that length is not a recognised selector for NSNull, which is true, and it seems to come up when the button is laying out its subviews, which it would do when you assign a new title. So I would focus your investigation in that area. Check to see what you are actually sending for the title of the button.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyCell* cell = (MyCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
if (nil == cell)
{
    NSArray* nibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCell" owner:nil options:nil];
cell = [nibContents objectAtIndex:0];
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
[cell.buttonGPS addTarget:self action:@selector(actionGPS:)       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.buttonCall addTarget:self action:@selector(actionCall:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

// gps button
[cell.buttonGPS setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

if (...condition...)
{
cell.buttonCall.enabled = NO;
}
else
{
cell.buttonCall.enabled = YES;
[cell.buttonCall setTitle:[...TheTitleString...] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Make these changes in ur code & check. I think some condition may be wrong, so b4 adding the target it was removed and when attempted it was crashing.